# angular ui-grid rendering buttons with ng-repeat in cell template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In grid items there is a column that offers a 'print reports' feature for each item. Each item has its type and report types are dynamically obtained from backend along with grid items data. I made grid cell template to render a button for each report type for every grid item:
This is 'columndefs' array member:

```
{
                name: 'documents',
                displayName: 'Dokumenti',
                enableHiding: false,
                enableSorting: false,
                enableColumnMenu: false,
                cellTemplate: '<button ng-repeat="i in row.entity.reports" ' + 
                    'ng-click="row.entity.printItemReport(i.reportType)" class="btn btn-sm btn-default " type="button" >' +
                    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i></button>'
}
```

Problem is, when I perform fast scrolling on grid, buttons are multiplied for small amount of time, and then the number of buttons are OK again.

[image]

I think that these buttons are real and clickable, so I am thinking that there is a problem with re-rendering a cell with template...

Comment: This is probably due to virtualization on the grid. I would try setting gridOptions.virtualizationThreshold = # > than your grid items, and gridOptions.columnVirtualizationThreshold = # > than the total columns to start troubleshooting. Basically, as you scroll, the grid is rendering on-the-fly. This feature allows having large datasets loaded, without having to have a DOM element for each. The downside can be things like this however, since your ng-repeat is being invoked each time you scroll. Between ng-repeat and the virtualization, there are a pile of calls made on each scroll.